# Proving that the infinite sequence $1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, \ldots$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

In **Example 5.1.13** of Analysis I by Terence Tao, we are asked to show that the infinite sequence

$$1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, \ldots$$

is unbounded by using the following result and definition:

**Proposition 4.4.1** (Interspersing of integers by rationals). Let $x$ be a rational number. Then there exists an integer $n$ such that $n \leq x < n + 1$. In fact, this integer is unique. In particular, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $N > x$.

**Definition 5.1.12** (Bounded sequences). Let $M \geq 0$ be rational. A finite sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ is bounded by $M$ iff $|a_i| \leq M$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. An infinite sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by $M$ iff $|a_i| \leq M$ for all $i \geq 1$. A sequence is said to be bounded iff it is bounded by $M$ for some rational $M \geq 0$.

---

**My Proof:**

The infinite sequence above is defined by
$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
n, &  n \ \text{is odd} \\
-n, &  n \ \text{is even}
\end{cases}
$$

Suppose, for sake of contradiction, the sequence is bounded. Then by Definition 5.1.12, there is some rational $M \geq 0$ such that $|a_i| \leq M$ for all $i \geq 1$. Then for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $i \geq k \geq 1$, we have $|a_k| \leq M$. It is easy to show that regardless of whether $k$ is odd or even, we have that $|a_k| = k$. Then

$$|a_k| \leq M \implies k \leq M$$

By Proposition 4.4.1, there exists an integer $m$ such that $m \leq M < m + 1$. Let's choose $k$ such that $k = m$. Then we have $k \leq M < k + 1$, implying

$$
M < k + 1 \implies |M| < |k+1| \implies M < |k+1| \implies M < |a_{k+1}|
$$

But this contradicts $|a_i| \leq M$ for all $i \geq 1$. Hence, no such $M$ could exist, implying the sequence is unbounded.

---

**Questions.**

1. Firstly, have I proven this correctly?
2. Is proof by contradiction the way to go? Is there a direct proof?
3. Was I allowed to choose $k$ such that $k=m$? If so, why?

Comment: Maybe I should have used the other part of the proposition, i.e. there exists a natural number $N > x$ and show that $N$ is in the given sequence, implying $N > M$?

Comment: AH I just found the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506955/proving-that-the-sequence-left-1n-1-n-right-n-1-infty-is-unbounded?rq=1

Should I close this?

Comment: It's ultimately up to you but I don't think that question addresses points 2. and 3. of yours specifically, so I personally would consider leaving it.

Comment: @BenSteffan someone closed it already lol... I was just about to say I'll leave it open.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Let me at least offer some thoughts about points 2. and 3. then: Proof by contradiction is the way to go; I don't think there is a direct proof given that you're so closely working with the definitions (How would a direct approach look like? You need to derive that no $M$ as in 5.1.12 exists, but you're given no tools, no theorems about when such an $M$ exists). For 3., you're not really choosing anything. Proposition 4.4.1 gives you an $m$ which you can use directly. You're effectively just renaming it to $k$ :)

Comment: @BenSteffan awesome, thanks for your help! Your points make sense to me.